# Scala: "id: Option[Long]"?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm new to both Scala & Playframework and am trying to grasp this idea of using `Option[Long]` or `Option[Int]` in classes. For an example, I see this a lot:

```
case class User(id: Option[Long],
    name: String)
```

Why would I using `Option[Long]` instead of just `Long` if it's required? How would I auto-increment `Long` (not `Option[Long]`) when inserting a new User?

Also, I not too familiar with the concept behind Futures and Promises, but could that be used?

ps sorry if these are dumb questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why would I be using Option[Long]?* Because the id will be auto-generated, i.e. you do not know what the id is, so you cannot set it. You create User(None, "SomeName"), and after you persist it, the id will be filled in by your persistence layer (which reads it from the DB).

A Future is a wrapper for a computation that will happen asynchronously. A Promise is an object that lets you communicate that a computation has completed successfully with a value, or failed with an exception. You can think of it as a wrapper for "some computation that may succeed or fail".

Comment: It seems like an awkward approach. Ideally you'd have an `Option[Long]` upon creation and a `Long` upon reading. I realize that this is hard when it's the database creating the `Long` in question, but it still seems suboptimal to have to deal with the `None` case when it's guaranteed to be a `Some` after you load it from the database.

Comment: @MysteriousDan you are right, and you may want to try if leaving out the id of your User completely helps. You can always use a (Long, User) tuple when you need it, or compose another case class SaveUser(id: Long, user: User), or even think about a generic Saved[Model] case class. If your data layout doesn't feel appropriate, change it until it fits perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for using an `Option` Type for the `id` field is to allow for transient object creation. If you're creating a new user, you need to instantiate an instance of `User` prior to it having a database-assigned `id`. In that case you would create it as `User(None, "bob")`.